# NSPredicate not executed

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate, magicalrecord

This is quite funny.
In my application I create thousands of entry in the database (in another thread, I'm using MagicalRecord). Everything seems working fine (from a background/foreground/context point of view).

When, in the main thread, I try to fetch the "just inserted" data, I discovered the following behaviour:

```
- (NSArray *) familiesInCompany:(Company *) company {
  NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company == %@", company];
  NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company.name == %@", company.name];

  NSArray *first = [Family MR_findAllSortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate1];
  NSArray *second = [Family MR_findAllSortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate2];
  NSArray *third = [Family MR_findByAttribute:@"company" withValue:company andOrderBy:@"name" ascending:YES];

  return second;
}
```

Now what I get is:

- first: is an empty array
- second: contains all the `Family` objects, as expected
- third: is an empty array.

By debugging the SQL statement I get the following:

The "first" statement:

> CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0000s for 0 rows.

The "second" statement":

> CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZCOMPANY FROM ZFAMILY t0 JOIN ZCOMPANY t1 ON t0.ZCOMPANY = t1.Z_PK WHERE  t1.ZNAME = ? ORDER BY t0.ZNAME
>
> CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0005s
>
> CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0007s for 2 rows.

The "third" statement:

> CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0000s for 0 rows.

The hilarious thing is that I close the application (I mean really manually terminate it) and and I open it back, all the three "fetching" statements work.

Why the first and the third fetch statements seem to never being executed? How to dig into the problem?

Comment: Having essentially the same problem I think, with an NSFetchedResultsController implementation.  Recently created records do not show up in the fetch result, but have been written to the persistent store when I check directly - the correct count even shows up in the relationship NSSet, but the NSPredicate doesn't see them.  Weird.  Using MagicalRecord 2 - used a 1.x version for a previous project and had no trouble, so I may just change course and use an older version.

Comment: Naive (and kind of off-topic) question: how are you logging the sql statements? I am really curious on how to do that in my app for better understanding predicates

Comment: @FelipeSabino check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging and http://d.pr/i/Lszs

Comment: @FabianoFrancesconi awesome, tks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same issue, this is what I figured out, and how I resolved it.

Magical Record has a root `NSManagedObjectContext` as a parent of the default `NSManagedObjectContext`.  When I create an `NSFetchedResultsController` in the default context, everything seems to work fine, just like you.

The problem is that all the *new* `NSManagedObject`'s come back with their still-temporary `ObjectID`'s. So, in my case, I was using an `NSPredicate` to scope a query on an associated table.  I didn't just call the association method because I didn't want to load *everything* into memory and wanted `NSFetchedResultsController` to handle changes, for me.

With the temporary `ObjectID` the query finds zero results and that's exactly what it displays.

Apparently the child context (default) doesn't get the benefit of the transformation to non-temporary ID's, even though it's been persisted to the backing store.

Even worse badness happened when I tried to force the issue with `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:`.  Core Data complained that it could not satisfy a fault for my instance.  Nevermind, there's no way it was actually a fault.  Simply refreshing the object had no effect, either.  I suspect this is a Core Data bug that hardly no one tickles because they just use the association methods to get an NSSet.

My fix was to use the parent context for the `NSFetchedResultsController`, just like in this question, [Magical Record, saving, and NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974713/magical-record-saving-and-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

I was already wrapping the default in a new child context upon edit and, therefore, copying the instances into that editing context with `createInContext`, so I didn't have to do any extra work beyond just adding `.parentContext` to the argument.

Incidentally, this only ever happened on new instances of the source of the association.  Once an instance was there from startup, it had a non-temporary `ObjectID` and never had the issue.

Comment: Sorry I think I missed something. Your advice is to create the "resources" using the "currentContext.parentContext"?

Comment: Not quite, that's what I pass to the Magical Record fetch* method.  Object creation (and modification) takes place in a child context with MR_defaultContext with it's parent.

Comment: Example code, [Model fetchAllSortedBy:@"qqq" ascending:NO withPredicate:predicate groupBy:@"qqq" delegate:self inContext:self.managedObjectContext.parentContext];  In this case, self.managedObjectContext is the same as MR_defaultContext.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue during my tests using an in-memory persistent store, and the problem went away as soon as I removed all context saves.  Presumably that meant the temporary ObjectID was still the correct one and it didn't matter it won't get refreshed on the default context after a save.

Comment: I think that something has to do with merging contexts. That is to say: the `- (void) MR_mergeChangesOnMainThread:(NSNotification *)notification` method is never called even when I call a MR_saveNestedContexts on a new context created via `MR_contextThatPushesChangesToDefaultContext`

Comment: This is so stupid. If I use "company.families" I get all the Family objects. If I do `[Family MR_findAllSortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company == %@", company] inContext:company.managedObjectContext]` it won't. What's wrong with MagicalRecord!?

Comment: I'm not sure it's Magical Record.  They're just using the pattern that Apple suggests in all the WWDC videos I've watched.  I just think we're using Core Data in a slightly weird way... most people probably just use the association method and call it a day.

Comment: I accept your answer as correct since it's the only thing left to do :(